# Bootstrap and permutation resampling. What is the difference?

Tags: statistics, bootstrap-sampling

Recently while passing one course (on datacamp) I got acquainted with two methods of resampling ( I used them to simulate statistical hypothesis) :

1.Bootstrap resampling when we choose samples with replacement of the size n from the main sample of the size n. We repeat this operation several times.

2.Permutation resampling when we scramble two arrays and relabel them. We also repeat this operation several times.

I am quite new in statistics and I have question: When it's better to choose th bootstrap and when permutation resampling?Are there any restrictions? Maybe there are any literature devoted to this?

Thanks for response!

Tim

Comment: Both have multiple iterations sometimes called re-sampling. A two-sample permutation test randomly reassigns observations to the two groups and recomputes a measure of difference btw the 2 samples for each reassignment. Reject at level $\alpha$ if fewer then proportion $\alpha$ of permuted measures is more extreme than observed measure without permutation. // Nonparametric bootstrap CI for a parameter is found by repeatedly re-sampling observations with replacement from among original data, re-estimating parameter for each re-sample and using quantiles of re-est'd params as confidence limits.

Comment: See [this Q and A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1590081/two-sample-permutation-tests-for-earthquake-magnitudes-before-and-after-a-damagi) for permutation test. // See Note at end of [this Q &  A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/483905/confidence-interval-for-variance-for-normal-distribution/483994#483994) for nonparametric bootstrap CI, plus another kind of bootstrap CI.

Comment: @BruceET and when it is possible to use permutation test for two samples? When we have a hypothesis that they are identically distributed ? But if not , will scrambling two arrays have any sense ? And for what kind of hypothesis it fits?

Comment: Good point. Opinions vary, So I'll stick to the obvious in this brief comment. If null hypothesis makes Gp1 & Gp 2 exchangeable, then permutation test is OK. But I'd be careful using permutation test to check for equal means knowing that variances are unequal. You might have exchangeability for one metric and not for another. // Permutation tests are useful in many cases in which standard tests are not, but all tests have assumptions. Beginning with random sampling of data from intended populations.